# Incomplete Class: Writing Constructors

Tags: java, class, constructor

> public class Pants {
>        private int size;
>        private String color; }

I need to write two constructors for the above code...

The default constructor should set the size to ten and the color to blue.

The second constructor should take two parameters: size and color.

The size must be an even number between 2 and 20. If a number outside of the range is submitted, the size should be set to 20.

If an odd number is submitted, the size should be set to the next largest acceptable size.

What is the best way to go about this?

> public class Pants {
>        private int size;
>        private String color; }
>
> Pants ( int size, String color){
>       size = 10;
>       color = blue; }
>
> public static int size if (x > 2 || x < 20)
>
> if((x%2)==0)
>       else { size =20 }

What I have so far... Probably terribly wrong.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code; do not post your attempt as a comment.

Comment: I have the default constructor, but not for sure the most effective (streamlined) way to approach the second constructor

Comment: **How** is this question a duplicate of that?

Answer (score -1):

```
public Pants() {
    this(10, "blue");
}

public Pants(int size, string color) {
    this.size = size < 2 || size > 20 ? 20 : size;
    if(this.size % 2 != 0)
        this.size++;
    this.color = color;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.